# MYSQL: Notifications when a new row values are added

Tags: java, mysql, notifications

i am working on a test tool, where QTP will publish results in MySQL DB. Now i have another application ( preferably Java ) which is going to manipulate the results. My requirement is whenever a new row value ( test results ) are updated in MySQL DB table, my Java application should receive a notification that new values are updated.
Thanks

Comment: You could implement a `poller` thread which constantly polls the table for any change.

Answer (score 0):

I think MariaDB Audit Plugin(https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/plugins/mariadb-audit-plugin/about-the-mariadb-audit-plugin/) is very helpful for your requirement.
in test case, parsing general log also possible.
that things do write to file. not notification. maybe you make text parser and notification application.